# Erro ao salvar com o cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Olá.

Não entendo o porque deste erro. O código aparentemente está correto.

https://pastebin.com/3NZwmFMM

Segue print do erro:

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/print_erro_firefox-jpg

Os campos da tabela usuário são:

table users
id, nome, email, password. Na tabela despesas tem a chave primária do
usuário fk_id_user references users (id). Não entendo erros deste
tipo!

Comment: Se quiser pode complementar a pergunta com o create da tabela Users

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Na verdade o erro é bem explicativo.

Você colocou uma pk na tabela **Users** que não existe:

```
public $primaryKey='id_despesa';
```

Ou seja o campo **id_despesa** não existe na tabela.

Comment: quando fiz a pergunta, elenquei os campos da tabela users. O id_despesa é chave primária da tabela despesas e a chave primária da tabela users é id. O campo fk_id_user é a chave extrangeira da tabela despesas.

Comment: o problema é que ele esta tentando buscar o id_despesa da tabela Users, ou seja falta relacionamento das tabelas um join resolveria, se este foi o motivo do downvote

Comment: alterei a linha public $primaryKey = 'id' e funcionou.